# Read image metadata for png images

Tags: php, image

I want to get metadata for png image. I used the function `exif_read_data()`. But this works for the *.jpg* and *.tiff* images only. How can I get metadata for *.png* images ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ZelluX That question is surely not well defined and actually the answer is something else.

Comment: @ZelluX i tried that link but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nikul Sorry about that, have you tried printing types of different segments and see if there is any tEXt or iTXt field?